# React Native Facebook Login build fail

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, react-native-fbsdk

I cannot set react-native-fbsdk on iOS. It works fine on Android but not on iOS.

After folowing every steps of official docs(https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) and other materials(Medium blogs, etc) and tried several times, I only got error message(Please click below link) like below or build fail on xcode.

ERROR MESSAGE ON IOS SIMULATOR:
**Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTFBLoginButton" was not found in the UIManager.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpsHY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbvqg.png)

here is my environment.
react-native : 0.56.0
react : 16.4.1
xcode : latest version
react-native-fbsdk : latest version

here is my AppDelegate.m

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@import GoogleMaps; //add this line if you want to use Google Maps

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBvofvg96WbweRSiW4-TwDkJBmPgzgk8_0"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"mdd_rn"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}

@end
```

here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>mdd_rn</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
      <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
      <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Feather.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
      <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
      <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
      <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
      <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
      <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
      <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like access to your photo gallery</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your camera</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to save photos to your photo gallery</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to your microphone (for videos)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>fb{MY_APP_ID}</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>{MY_APP_ID}</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>{MY_APP_NAME}</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Is there any solutions or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe react-native-fbsdk is not linked correctly.

Comment: @khalid Thanks for your comment. How can I link properly? I tried react-native install react-native-fbsdk & react-native link react-native-fbsdk and also followed other settings that official docs said. Or What data do I need to provide more to explain my situation now?

Comment: let me know your fbsdk location.

Comment: Did you installed using cocoa or manullay?

Comment: @khalid Actually, I tried both ways(cocoa and manual).  my fbsdk location is ~/Documents/FacebookSDK . I'm wondering if I have to choose one not tried both.

Comment: was you able to solve it. ping me on twitter khalid_ansari1

Comment: @SanghoonLee did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even after following the guides very carefully. Other answers haven't helped me, it was still just not working.

Eventually I managed to make it work after dragging the `RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj` from `./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios` in the `Libraries` folder within the Xcode project. Once it has been added, you have to expand it and drag the `libRCTFBSDK.a` to your target's build phases.

[image]

[image]

You will also need to re-build the project from Xcode or run `react-native run-ios`.

I hope this helps you.